# Given a block device file, how can I list all relevant partions?

Tags: linux, usb, device

**Given a device file *(ex: `/dev/sda`)* how can I get a list of all relevant partitions?**

Expected input:

```
/dev/sda
```

Expected output:

```
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
...
```

I know there are many ways to get information about block devices, such as `lsblk`, `fdisk`, and `blkid` to name a few, but I want a solution that is the most succinct (ie, doesn't use an enormous number of pipes to `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `uniq` etc).

**What is the most condensed one liner to solve this problem?**

**Notes:**
I'm using linux (specifically ubuntu) and using either terminal or shell script to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [DopeGhoti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20246) answered my question the most succinctly on Unix & Linux Stack Overflow [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461628/given-a-block-device-file-how-can-i-list-all-relevant-partions):

> With ls:
>
> `$ ls -1 /dev/sda?*`
>   `/dev/sda1`
>   `/dev/sda2`
>   `/dev/sda3`

Answer (score 0):

How about 1 pipe:

```
lsblk | grep -o 'sda[0-9]'
```

The -o option is for "only matching". It cuts off the parts of the line after the match.